# What does it mean in groupingBy in the Java API and how to use it?

Tags: java, api, collectors

I'm looking at the Java API regarding Collectors.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.stream.Collector-

```
public static <T,K,D,A,M extends Map<K,D>> Collector<T,?,M> groupingBy(Function<? super T,? extends K> classifier,
                                                                       Supplier<M> mapFactory,
                                                                       Collector<? super T,A,D> downstream)
```

> **Type Parameters:**
>
> T - the type of the input elements
>
> K - the type of the keys
>
> A - the intermediate accumulation type of the downstream collector
>
> D - the result type of the downstream reduction
>
> M - the type of the resulting Map
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> classifier - a classifier function mapping input elements to keys
>
> downstream - a Collector implementing the downstream reduction
>
> mapFactory - a function which, when called, produces a new empty Map
>   of the desired type
>
> **Returns:**
>
> a Collector implementing the cascaded group-by operation

From the first line of code, I understand that it is a public static method but what does it mean by `<T, K, D, A, M extends Map<K, D>>`?

And then from `Collector<T, ?, M>`, I can understand that it returns a Collector but what is the meaning of the `?`.

Additionally, I went onto the page of one of the parameters, `Supplier` and since it's a functional interface it has only one abstract method called `get` but I simply do not know how to use it at all. And the book which I'm going through teaches us to use `TreeMap::new`.

My confusion here is how come the parameter requires something that implements the `Supplier` interface but yet we are able to use the method reference instead?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This may be too broad for a single question. You've asked at least two if not three questions here. :-) How generic type parameters work, how methods can be mapped to functional interfaces...

Comment: For instance, `<T, K, D, A, M extends Map<K, D>>` just means that the method is going to use generic type parameters called `T`, `K`, `D`, `A`, and `M`, and that `M` has to extend `Map<K, D>`. But that doesn't answer your overall question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `<T, K, D, A, M extends Map<K, D>>` means that this method uses 5 generic type parameters - `T`, `K`, `D`, `A` and `M` where `M` must implement `Map<K, D>`.
2. `?` denotes a wild card i.e. you don't care what type that is. Note that this is different from adding another generic type parameter. If it were another generic type parameter, say, `U`, it can be referred later in the code. You *care* about it.
3. `Supplier` represents a method that accepts no parameters and returns a value of some type. `TreeMap::new` takes no parameters and it gives you a `TreeMap`, so this method reference can be used here.

Answer (score 1):

`<T,K,D,A,M extends Map<K,D>>` - these are generic parameters for this function, that are used as this functions' parameters and result generic parameters. So, your parameters have to be:

- `Function<? super T,? extends K> classifier` - function that takes `T` and returns `K`
- `Supplier<M> mapFactory` - supplier creates `M`
- `Collector<? super T,A,D> downstream` - collector with `T`, `A` and `D` parameters (look further explanation and documentation for details)

And also this function produces `Collector<T,?,M>` - here goes `T` and `M`. All these parameters should be specified either explicitly or implicitly.

About collector parameters, you can just go to [Collector documentation page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html) and see, that second generic parameter for `Collector` class is

> the mutable accumulation type of the reduction operation (often hidden as an implementation detail)

Usually, you don't care about this mutable accumulation type, because in the end you need only result, which, in this case, is `M`.

About supplier - i would also advise to go to [documentation page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html). It's an interface with one method `T get()`. And this `TreeMap::new` can be represented as `() -> new TreeMap<>()`. If that is also unclear, then you probably need to read some tutorials about anonymous classes, functional interfaces and lambda functions (and method references) in general.